# How to change the width and height of an html file using java

Tags: java, android

I wanted to change width="xyz" , where (xyz) can be any particular value to width="300". I researched on regular expressions and this was the one I am using a syntax with regular expression

```
String holder = "width=\"340\"";
String replacer="width=\"[0-9]*\"";
theWeb.replaceAll(replacer,holder);
```

where theWeb is the string
. But this was not getting replaced. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is correct.  One thing you might be forgetting is that in Java all string methods do not affect the current string - they only return a new string with the appropriate transformation.  Try this instead:

```
String replacement = 'width="340"';
String regex = 'width="[0-9]*"';
String newWeb = theWeb.replaceAll(regex, replacement); // newWeb holds new text
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use `JSoup` for **manipulating and extracting** data, etc. from `Html`

**See this link for more details:**

http://jsoup.org/

Comment: Is there a way by which i can change it using regular expression. Actually it a text file.